# F# FAKE will not execute powershell script file

Tags: powershell, f#, chocolatey, f#-fake, f#-fake-4

**Update:** The actual cause of the issue was the '\' being round the wrong way, should have been './GenerateNuspecFile.ps1' - weird thing with F# parsing.

---

I am unable to run a ps1 script file from F# FAKE.

Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23351432/executing-a-powershell-script-in-fake) which works well for running a chocolatey cpack

```
#r "packages/FAKE.3.12.2/tools/FakeLib.dll"
#r "System.Management.Automation"
#r "System.Core.dll"

open Fake
open System.Management.Automation
...

Target "GenerateNuspecFile" <| fun _ -> 
    PowerShell.Create()
        .AddScript("Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { cd './chocolatey' | iex .\GenerateNuspecFile.ps1 }")
        .Invoke()
        |> Seq.iter (printfn "%O")
...
```

This is not actually running the script file that I am trying to run.
Set-ExecutionPolicy is "unrestricted"

Comment: You should probably inspect `Streams.Error` on the `PowerShell` object for errors, but you have not assigned it to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your powershell script has some issues, and would not work even if run from the command line.

In particular, `cd .\somedir | iex .\SomeScript.ps1` is nonsensical - you are piping the result of a `cd` (which is `$null`, since `cd` doesn't return anything) to `Invoke-Expression`, which is basically saying "run this $null as a script.". `Invoke-Command` should not be needed at all.

If your goal is simply to run `GenerateNuSpecFile.ps1`, your script should just be:

```
.AddScript("cd '<somepath>'; .\GenerateNuspecFile.ps1")
```

Or

```
.AddScript("& '<somepath>\GenerateNuspecFile.ps1'")
```