# F# Run Powershell Script As Target

Tags: powershell, f#, f#-fake

Trying to run a powershell script using F# FAKE but nothing happens... there are no errors, the target loads but nothing actually is run.

```
// include Fake lib
#r "packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"
#r "System.Management.Automation"

open System
open System.IO
open System.Diagnostics
open System.Management.Automation

    Target "Powershell" <| fun _ ->
    PowerShell.Create()
      .AddScript("& 'build-database.ps1'")
      .AddParameter("BuildVersion", version)
      .AddParameter("Debug", "")
      .Invoke()
      |> Seq.iter (printfn "%O")

// Dependencies
"Clean"
  ==> "Powershell"

// start build
RunTargetOrDefault "Powershell"
```

Am I missing something? Without any error I am not sure what the issue is.

*** Updated ***

This is the powershell script I am testing with, FAKE does nothing.

```
New-Item c:\AnEmptyFile.txt -ItemType file
```

Comment: How do you know that nothing is run? Can you add some tracing to `build-database.ps1` to see what it's doing? Can you then add some tracing to the `Target "Powershell"` function in the FAKE script?

Comment: The powershell script creates a text file in a folder. I run the script from the command line and it works, file is created. When using FAKE the output says the target completed successfully... though nothing from the script is ever outputted and no file created.

Comment: Does it always create the same file or does it depend on parameters? Can you make it always create the same file in a predefined absolute location and see if that happens?

Comment: It is the same file every time. At this point I am trying to simply run a script that creates a helloworld.txt and it works, except in FAKE.

Comment: Is the path to the file absolute?

Comment: Couldn't tell you since the documentation on FAKE is scarce. my build.fsx file and this script are in the same folder. the script outputs the helloworld file into the same folder.

Comment: Inside the PS1 file, change the path to absolute. I mean, not `"helloworld.txt"`, but `"c:\whatever\helloworld.txt"`. Then see if the file appears in `c:\whatever`.

Comment: am I calling the powershell script correctly? not even sure at this point if that is right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing a Powershell Script in Fake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23351432/executing-a-powershell-script-in-fake)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured out another way to do it that works. In case someone else has the need to call a powershell script from within F# FAKE the following method worked for me.

```
Target "Powershell" (fun _ ->

        let p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();              
        p.StartInfo.FileName <- "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments <- ("/c powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted .\\script.ps1)
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput <- true
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute <- false
        p.Start() |> ignore

        printfn "Processing..."
        printfn "%A" (p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd())
        printfn "Finished"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to use `Shell.Execute` and invoke `powershell.exe`:

```
Target "ImportDb" (fun _ ->
    Shell.Exec("powershell.exe", "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File script.ps1") |> ignore)
```